# Programmatically add multiple images inside of tablerow cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7

I need to add multiple images to a cell... Which is the easy part. My problem is I am unsure of the amount of thumbnail photos that are inside of a table row. Something like this:

[image]

So if I don't know the size of my images for each row, I suspect if I use `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` inside of the `heightForRowAtIndexPath`the row height will adjust automatically? My question is directed more towards how to dynamically add multiple images to row without knowing the number of images. In your answer, don't feel obligated to include the sections if you don't want to. Just need help with dynamically fitting multiple images inside of one row, without knowing the number of images.

Answer (score 1):

you can use Collection View instead of adding lots of images to one cell.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CollectionViewBasics/CollectionViewBasics.html

Comment: Correct. Further the provided image suggests using a CollectionView inside a TableViewCell